# Why is Chrome Browser never showing update notes, and how to check the notes if possible

Tags: google-chrome

For a while I've been clicking on the toggle that turns green when there are chrome updates, and let Chrome update itself. But it really makes me feel uncomfortable since I have no idea what Chrome is updating. As a developer myself, I'm also concerned if this update will affect my code compatibility for other browsers since I develop primarily using Chrome.

Question is, is there any way to set up Chrome so that it informs me what it is updating and asks for my confirmation before doing everything under the hood?

Comment: You can check the [release notes](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/) yourself before updating.

Comment: Much appreciated! Maybe this could be an idea for a Chrome extension ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there any way to set up Chrome so that it informs me what it is going to update?

I don't believe this is possible.

However, if you are manually allowing the update, then I suggest you look at the [release notes](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/) in the "Release updates from the Chrome team Blog".

- A blog entry is provided for each Stable, Beta and Dev Channel Update.
- Links to the logs for each release are also in most blog entries.